# Printing Objects in Django

Tags: python, django

So I've connected Django to a pre-existing database successfully (inspect, validate and sync) and I've created an app and a project and all that (I'm reading the Django book and I'm on chapter 5), but when I actually run it and print stuff, I get an (assumed) error. While in python, I properly import what I need (`from myapp.models import Artist`) but if I try to print, for example, the first five rows in the table (`print Artist.objects.all()[:5]`), I get this:

```
[<Artist: Artist object>, <Artist: Artist object>, <Artist: Artist object>, <Artist: Artist object>, <Artist: Artist object>]
```

Why doesn't it actually print the values instead of what seems to be a placeholder? Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Django uses an ORM (Object-Relational Mapper) that translates data back and forth between Python objects and database rows. So when you use it to get an item from the database, it converts it into a Python object.

If that object doesn't define how to display itself as text, Django does it for you. Python does the same thing:

```
>>> class MyObject(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> [MyObject(), MyObject()]
[<__main__.MyObject object at 0x0480E650>,
 <__main__.MyObject object at 0x0480E350>]
```

---

If you want to see all of the actual values for the row for each object, use [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Here is the example from the docs:

```
# This list contains a Blog object.
>>> Blog.objects.filter(name__startswith='Beatles')
[<Blog: Beatles Blog>]

# This list contains a dictionary.
>>> Blog.objects.filter(name__startswith='Beatles').values()
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Beatles Blog', 'tagline': 'All the latest Beatles news.'}]
```

Comment: Well after trying jdi's solution, data actually appeared, but this is more of what I was trying to achieve. I wish I could accept both answers! D:

Comment: @GabeC.: My feelings wont be hurt. agf ended up providing the info you really needed :-)

Comment: How are we supposed to print an object's values in a simple way, when we are manipulating the model instance which doesn't have a `values()` method?

Comment: values() is used for filter, but I want same this for get() method.

Comment: Yeah, be careful folks, many ORM objects don't have a values() method and trying to call it will throw an error.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE:**
In **Python 3.x**, use `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`

What you are seeing is a list of Artist model instances. Your values are in a python object. If you would like to make the representation of those instances more helpful, you should define the `__unicode__` method for them to print something useful:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#unicode

Its not a placeholder, its the actual object's representation, converted to unicode.

Comment: Ahh, there we go. I just defined the unicode for Artist and tried it again, and it works; thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use print method
ovveride the **unicode** method in the model itself

```
 def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (self.id)
```

here an example model

```
class unit(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (self.name)

print(unit.objects.all())
[unit: KG, unit: PCs]
```

Comment: Could you please help me to understand how can I remove model name `unit` from `[unit: KG, unit: PCs]`  
for an instance, in a for loop I want to print like below: `A from KG`  
`B from PCs` here `A, B` will be from another model and `KG, PC` are from model `unit`.

Comment: That is a separate question not a comment and we need to see more of your code.