# If I don't know, what is in array or object, how I can show it in Django in console or page like php var_dump?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I want to know what the array contains, like JS concole.log() or php var_dump

```
def showArticle(request):
     articles = Article.objects.all()
     return render(request, 'article.html', {'articles': articles})
```

My template:

```
<pre>
    {{ articles }}
</pre>
```

It shows:

```
<QuerySet [<Article: Article object>]>
```

If I use

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {{ article }}
{% endfor %}
```

It will show the same

```
    Article object
    Article object
    Article object
```

and if I want show request.

```
def printRequest(request):
     req = str(request)
     print(request)
```

it prints only:

```
<WSGIRequest: GET '/'>
```

Comment: This looks like a [duplicate of your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47407641/1324033), which also mysteriously got a strange number of upvotes..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing Objects in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150305/printing-objects-in-django)

Comment: @Sayse Thank you. It was my question)

Comment: @Sayse The mystery has vanished FYI :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {{ article.values }}
{% endfor %}
```

But a debugger is really what you want for this kind of stuff. Or even just printing to the console.

[Printing Objects in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150305/printing-objects-in-django)